# Equation for Atmospheric Pressure Tide

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling, barometric-pressure

Using Pressure sensors - I found out that there is a daily pressure wave-like pattern with peaks at 9:00 & 21:00 (local time).

I want to construct an equation to explain this phenomena, probably something that relates the solar radiation and the latitude to the pressure measurement.

Can anyone refer me to a model or articles regarding this ?

Thanks !

Comment: so would you want to model this as dissipative waves ? Exponential growth and dissipation ?

Comment: or is there any dispersive component as well ?

Comment: could you clarify at what height the measurement was made - sea level or at an altitude?

Comment: The Height is near sea-level (roughly), for all the measurements. The model I'm searching for is one who can explain why there are 2 peaks each day and why at the specific local times. My guess is that it has something with the solar heating - but the highs at 9:00 and 21:00 doesn't fit that reasoning

Comment: how long are the measurements ? Do you have records going back years ? Regarding modeling I would assume it would be some sort of a dispersive or dissipative  wave

Comment: I have records for only 1.5 years, but the daily highs and lows are clearly visible.

Comment: How accurate of a model do you want? A simple mathematical model you could construct would be to take a Fast Fourier Transform  of the data (possibly filter the spurious freqencies) and use that as a best guess. Another model would be climatology. Another model could be use a Markov chain, etc.

Comment: I'm searching for a model to explain the results - the physical phenomena. Maybe phase lock between gravity tides and solar heating ?

Comment: @ValientProcess You could look at using wavelets. First remove the mean, do a detrend then calculate the wavelet.